# Pycord parameter type for slash command with context-dependent auto completion

Tags: python, discord, bots, pycord

For the sake of a simple example, assume I want a bot that provides a command `/ping_channel <channel>` that takes a channel as parameter and then the bot writes a message to that channel. With Pycord, I can easily achieve this like so:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="ping_channel", guild_ids=[...])
async def ping_channel(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await channel.send("ping")
    await ctx.respond(f"I sent a message to: {channel}")
```

This provides the user with a nice auto-completion list of channels. However, I want to enable the user to use the bot to ping private channels they are not a member of. I am aware that I can provide a list of channels myself with something like this:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="ping_channel", guild_ids=[...])
async def ping_channel(
    ctx,
    channel_name: Option(str, "channel", choices=[OptionChoice("general"), OptionChoice("lobby")]),
):
```

Unfortunately, using something like

```
choices=[OptionChoice(channel.name) for channel in bot.guilds[0].channels]
```

to get an OptionChoice for each existing channel fails as this is apparently evaluated before the bot knows any guilds (i.e., bot.guilds is empty).

So here is my question: Is there a way to get custom auto-completion for slash commands that can depend on the context (e.g., giving a list of all channels)?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want are the guild's channels you can simply use the `discord.abc.GuildChannel` type for your option.

```
@bot.slash_command(name="test_command", guild_ids=[...])
@option("channel", discord.abc.GuildChannel)
async def test_cmd(ctx, channel):
   pass
```

However, this also counts the categories (as well as StageChannels and ForumChannels), so you might want to use a `typing.Union[discord.TextChannel, discord.VoiceChannel]`.